# How to solve the hazy display in Win8?

Tags: display, desktop-computer

Whenever I am using Win XP it occurs rarely but in case of Win7 or Win8 it occurs frequently in web browser like Chrome, Firefox etc and in video players also

[image: Example]

Comment: What sort of display and how is it connected?

Comment: it is a aoc lcd monitor. connected by two cables

Comment: Technically correct but not very useful. VGA, DVI, HDMI or DP? Why two cables? Are you including power?

Comment: And what is the model number of your monitor and display card?

Comment: Yes I am including power. The model number is AOC 831W and display adapter is NVIDIA GeForce 7025 / NVIDIA nForce 630a

Comment: Can you try booting a Linux distribution from a USB (like Ubuntu)